# Solution to the following Fredholm integral equation?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, integral-equations

I have the following integral equation
$$1 = \int_{-L}^{L} K(s-t)f(t)\mathrm{d}t,$$
where we are solving for $F = \int_{-L}^{L}f(s)\mathrm{d}s$.

That is, $f(t)$ is an unknown function that we do not necessarily need to know. If it helps, the Kernel is $K(x) = -2\,{\frac {{x}^{4}+{\epsilon}^{2}{x}^{2}+3/4\,{\epsilon}^{4}}{
 \left( {\epsilon}^{2}+{x}^{2} \right) ^{5/2}}}.
$ **Does anyone have any ideas on how to find $F$?**

P.S.: if it makes things simpler, what if we extend the integration limits to the real line, I.e. $[-L,L]\rightarrow[-\infty,\infty]$? Note that $K(x)$ does not have a computable Fourier transform.

Comment: so, the equality is independent on the value of $s$?

Comment: Ah true. The LHS used to read $u(s)$ but I set it to $1$ to make things easier. So I guess it is independent of $s$

Comment: so what happens when $s\rightarrow \pm \infty$?

Comment: For any fixed value of $L$, the left-hand side is independent on $s$.  So the right-hand side must be likewise.  Setting $s=0$ and exploiting the evenness of $K$, we find the $f(t)$ cannot be unique since we can add to any candidate for $f$ an odd function, say $g(t)$.  That is, if $f$ satisfies the integral equation, then so does $f+g$ for any odd function $g$

Comment: @MarkViola  That's a good observation. Although can you not say the same about $F=\int_{-L}^Lf(s)ds$? I.e., Could $F$ still have a unique solution?

Comment: @user619894 I believe $K$ goes to 0 as $s$ goes to infinity

Comment: So basically, a contradiction? If the result is independent of s, we must have $f\rightarrow \infty$ for s→∞

Comment: I had an idea but idk what's it seems a bit complicated : suppose we set g a function orthogonal to K(s-x) $\forall  s$, taking $\int_{-L}^L p(x)q(x)dx$ as a scalar product. Then add a multiple of K to obtained the desired scalar product result 1 ?